# Spring Integration - Sharing lock across steps

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, locking, spring-integration

I have the following setup: a number of devices send data via HTTP to my backend, where multiple instances a receiver component are running. I need to process the data and then send it to another external partner, who needs this data in timestamp order. So I came up with the following architecture:

1. There are n receiver instances running, with a load balancer in front of them, so they potientially get data from all devices. These instances process each incoming data by adding some information and then put the data into a Redis Sorted Set (there is one for each device). After this they send a message (via Redis) about how many data entries are currently in the set.
2. There are m processing instances whose task is it to send the data to the external partner. They listen to the messages sent by the receivers and if the number of entries inside a set is larger than some threshold, they retrieve the data from the queue, add some other information and then send it to the external partner.

The problem I have is the timestamp order requirement. I have n and m instances, each one running multiple threads. For the processing instances, who all receive the messages from the receiver, I thought about doing the retrieval of the data from the set and sending it to the external partner inside a shared Redis lock for the queue associated with the message (and the respective device). But currently there are multiple Spring Integration steps that are part of the processing flow: get the data from the queue -> transform it for sending -> send it via an HTTP outbound channel. I thought about using a lock that is obtained in the first step (getting the data from the queue) and released in the last step (after sending it via the outbound channel). In case of an error the lock would be released in the error processing step.

Are there any ideas for alternatives to this? I was thinking about sending the lock as part of the message header through the remaining flow and then release it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say about ordering, you should consider to use [PriorityChannel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-prioritychannel) or [Resequencer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#resequencer) to reorder records before sending to the external partner.
Both of them can be configured with the shared `MessageStore`.